# Channels with Grids not retaining data

Tags: channel-form, grid

**Data**:

I have 2 pages with {exp:channel:form} each using the same channel `foo`

Channel `foo` has 4 fields with Grid fieldtypes, `a`, `b` `c`, `d`

Page `1` shows a form to edit `a`

Page `2` shows a form to edit `b`,`c` and `d`

**This is the problem that I have.**

When I try to submit Page `1`, `a` data is saved but `b`, `c`, `d` data is erased.

When I try to submit Page `2`, `b`, `c`, and `d` data is saved but `a` data is erased.

How do I fix this?

UPDATE:

It seems that this is a problem with grid fieldtype.

When you save any channel that has a grid field using {exp:channel:form}, if that grid field is not included in the form, it will be reset/erased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like this bug:
https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19772

and was resolved with the recent 2.7.3 release. Or you can see how to correct it via the link above.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a clear bug that needs to be [**reported to EllisLab**](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/submit)...

In the meantime, I suggest using [**Matrix field**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/matrix) instead to get your project moving forward.